# What are the possible endings in Replica Island, and how do you achieve each of them?

Tags: replica-island

In the game Replica Island for Android, what are the different ways the game can end? Is there a way to avoid killing either boss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 endings, and you get them based on which boss you choose to fight in the last level.

The one in the right (kobach), the one in the left (roduku), and the one up, the Source.

Unfortunately you need to start the whole game again to see the other endings (unless you somehow edit the save games to start only the last one).

The best possible ending is choosing to kill the Source. I did not play it again to see the other endings though.